# exporting to excel from asp.net getting line breaks to display

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have seen a number of questions on this subject - but I can't get the suggestions to work. I am exporting a dataset to excel and am using the following to set up the basic formatting. I am setting up the basic formatting by building this string:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat(@"<?xml version=""1.0""?>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@"<?mso-application progid=""Excel.Sheet""?>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@"<Workbook xmlns=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet""{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" xmlns:o=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office""{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" xmlns:x=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel""{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" xmlns:ss=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet""{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" xmlns:html=""http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" <Styles>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" <Style ss:ID=""Default"" ss:Name=""Normal"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" <Alignment ss:Vertical=""Bottom""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" <Borders/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" <Font ss:FontName=""Calibri"" x:Family=""Swiss"" ss:Size=""11"" ss:Color=""#000000""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" <Interior/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" <NumberFormat/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" <Protection/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" <Style ss:ID=""s62"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" <Font ss:FontName=""Calibri"" x:Family=""Swiss"" ss:Size=""11"" ss:Color=""#000000""{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" ss:Bold=""1""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" <Style ss:ID=""s63"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" <NumberFormat ss:Format=""Short Date""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat(@" </Styles>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.Append(@"{0}\r\n</Workbook>");
return sb.ToString();
```

In a separate function I am replacing

```
<br > with &#10;
```

and this works, up to a point. If I have:

```
Bill<br />Fred<br />Jim
```

as the data for a cell, it is appearing in the excel spreadsheet as:

```
BillFredJim
```

If I click the Wrap Text icon in Excel - the text appears as it should within the cell. I.e. as

```
Bill
Fred
Jim
```

I have read that I need to add:

```
ss:WrapText=""1""
```

How can I include that in my StringBuilder so that Excel does it automatically?

I tried adding it to the line:

```
sb.AppendFormat(@" <Style ss:ID=""Default"" ss:Name=""Normal"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
```

so it read:

```
sb.AppendFormat(@" <Style ss:ID=""Default"" ss:WrapText=""1"" ss:Name=""Normal"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
```

but, when I try to open the generated excel spreadsheet, it says it is corrupt. How can I make it so that when excel opens, the text in the cells wrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing WrapText in Style try doing it in Alignment:

```
sb.AppendFormat(@" <Alignment ss:WrapText=""1"" ss:Vertical=""Bottom""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the Excel Library for this kind of task. Has a pretty good result!

https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/